# jquery click event ONLY when wrapped element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<ul class="treeList2">
<li class="topLevel marked checked"><div class="tlWrap clearfix"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox"><strong>Level name here blah blah   <span>(3)</span></strong></div></li>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    $(function(){           

        $('.treeList2 li.topLevel .tlWrap').click(function(){
            alert(this);
        });
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

The problem is that this fires when I click the checkbox (which i don't want). **I Only want to alert(this) when the 'div' is clicked** (I do this so that I can change the div background). 
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can prevent the click event on the checkbox from bubbling up to the parent like this:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/K64yx/)

See http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: He wants it the other way around -> Binding on parent, shouldn't trigger on child

Comment: That is what I answered. See the demo.

Answer (score 2):

check if the target is not input element and then only alert.

```
$(function(){   
        $('.treeList2 li.topLevel .tlWrap').click(function(e){
            if (e.target.nodeName !== 'INPUT') {
                alert(this);
            }               
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, you need to call the parent?

```
$('.treeList2 li.topLevel .tlWrap').parent().click( ...
```

Although if you want to change the parent div when the checkbox is clicked:

```
$('.treeList2 li.topLevel .tlWrap').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().css('background-color','red');
});
```

[edit]
Sorry, I mis-read the html.
There's a 'not' function that you can exclude elements with:

```
$('.treeList2 li.topLevel .tlWrap').not('input').click( ...
```

This will fire when anything in the div is clicked on, except the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the element that triggered the event (e.target) has a class of `tlWrap`.

```
$(function(){
        $('.treeList2 li.topLevel .tlWrap').click(function(e){
            if($(e.target).hasClass("tlWrap")) {            
               alert(this);
            }
        });
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsadasivan/BkgtZ/).